# How to create a new row in a query based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem statement:

I have a table of the following information:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| equipment | equipment_state | equipment_state_in  | equipment_state_out |     shift_begin     |       shift_end        |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| A         | X               | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 04:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
| A         | Y               | 2020-12-05 04:00:01 | 2020-12-05 08:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
| A         | Z               | 2020-12-05 08:00:01 | 2020-12-05 13:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

As seen, this table represents the state of a piece of equipment through time, with the shift that the state occurred in added as context. The issue is, an equipment state can continue into the next shift while beginning in the first shift. This is seen in the last row.

Solution:

I am looking for a solution that will apply logic to the query in order to detect when equipment state bleeds into the next shift, and thus creates another row in order to separate the information, like such:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| equipment | equipment_state | equipment_state_in  | equipment_state_out |     shift_begin     |       shift_end        |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| A         | X               | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 04:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
| A         | Y               | 2020-12-05 04:00:01 | 2020-12-05 08:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
| A         | Z               | 2020-12-05 08:00:01 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:00:00 | 2020-12-05 12:00:00    |
| A         | Z               | 2020-12-05 12:00:01 | 2020-12-05 13:00:00 | 2020-12-05 00:12:00 | 2020-12-05 24:00:00    |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

As seen, the state z from 8:00 - 13:00 is still captured, but now its separated so that the 12:00-13:00 section is within the correct shift window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are we to assume that all shifts exist and that they are either from midnight to noon or noon to midnight?

Comment: 2020-12-05 24:00:00 should be 2020-12-06 00:00:00 to be a valid datetime.  If they are strings, the logic of comparing 2020-12-05 24:00:00 to 2020-12-06 00:00:00 would be added complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this recursive CTE a try. The anchor is the original data with the equipment out time set to the shift end time if it is past it. Extra columns are added to the anchor to store information for the remaining equipment time, if any. The next shift period is also calculated at this time to simplify the recursive part of the query.

The recursive query applies the same logic to the remaining equipment time. The remaining equipment time will be reduced by one shift each iteration so the recursion will eventually stop.

```
WITH src as ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        VALUES 
            ('A', 'X', 
                CAST('2020-12-05 00:00:00' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 04:00:00' as datetime), 
                CAST('2020-12-05 00:00:00' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 12:00:00' as datetime)), 
            ('A', 'Y', 
                CAST('2020-12-05 04:00:01' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 08:00:00' as datetime), 
                CAST('2020-12-05 00:00:00' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 12:00:00' as datetime)),
            ('A', 'Z', 
                CAST('2020-12-05 08:00:01' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 13:00:00' as datetime), 
                CAST('2020-12-05 00:00:00' as datetime), CAST('2020-12-05 12:00:00' as datetime))
    ) t (equipment, equipment_state, equipment_state_in, equipment_state_out, shift_begin, shift_end)
), split as (
    SELECT equipment, 
        equipment_state, 
        equipment_state_in,
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out > shift_end THEN shift_end ELSE equipment_state_out END as [equipment_state_out],
        shift_begin, 
        shift_end, 
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out > shift_end THEN shift_end END as [equipment_state_in_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out > shift_end THEN equipment_state_out END as [equipment_state_out_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out > shift_end THEN shift_end END as [shift_begin_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out > shift_end THEN DATEADD(hour, 12, shift_end) END as [shift_end_remainder]
    FROM src
    UNION ALL
    SELECT equipment, 
        equipment_state, 
        equipment_state_in_remainder as [equipment_state_in],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out_remainder > shift_end_remainder THEN shift_end_remainder ELSE equipment_state_out_remainder END as [equipment_state_out],
        shift_begin_remainder as [shift_begin], 
        shift_end_remainder as [shift_end], 
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out_remainder > shift_end_remainder THEN shift_end_remainder END as [equipment_state_in_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out_remainder > shift_end_remainder THEN equipment_state_out_remainder END as [equipment_state_out_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out_remainder > shift_end_remainder THEN shift_end_remainder END as [shift_begin_remainder],
        CASE WHEN equipment_state_out_remainder > shift_end_remainder THEN DATEADD(hour, 12, shift_end_remainder) END as [shift_end_remainder]
    FROM split
    WHERE equipment_state_in_remainder IS NOT NULL
)
select * from split
```

Comment: The 'strings' are indeed datetimes already (shouldn't have had 24:00:00 in the question). But upon my preliminary attempts, this recursion methods seems to do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using more intuitive and programmatic way of looping and comparing -

--- One table variable with id as row number to be used for looping

--- Another table variable to hold the final result

```
declare @TempTable as TABLE(Id  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                        equipment       NVARCHAR(1),
                        equipment_state NVARCHAR(1),
                        equipment_state_in DATETIME,
                        equipment_state_out DATETIME,
                        shift_begin     DATETIME,
                        shift_end       DATETIME)

declare @Output as TABLE(equipment          NVARCHAR(1),
                        equipment_state NVARCHAR(1),
                        equipment_state_in DATETIME,
                        equipment_state_out DATETIME,
                        shift_begin     DATETIME,
                        shift_end       DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TempTable(equipment, equipment_state, equipment_state_in, equipment_state_out, shift_begin, shift_end)
SELECT equipment, equipment_state, equipment_state_in, equipment_state_out, shift_begin, shift_end from OriginalTable
    
DECLARE     @RowNum                 INT = 1;
DECLARE     @equipment              NVARCHAR(1),
            @equipment_state        NVARCHAR(1),
            @equipment_state_in     DATETIME,
            @equipment_state_out    DATETIME,
            @shift_begin            DATETIME,
            @shift_end              DATETIME

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TempTable WHERE Id = @RowNum)
BEGIN
    SELECT @equipment = equipment, @equipment_state = equipment_state, @equipment_state_in = equipment_state_in, @equipment_state_out = equipment_state_out, @shift_begin = shift_begin, @shift_end = shift_end FROM @TempTable WHERE Id = @RowNum;
    WHILE (@equipment_state_out > @shift_end)
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Output(equipment, equipment_state, equipment_state_in, equipment_state_out, shift_begin, shift_end)
            VALUES (@equipment, @equipment_state, @equipment_state_in, @shift_end, @shift_begin, @shift_end)

            SET @equipment_state_in = @shift_end;
            SET @shift_begin = @shift_end;
            SET @shift_end = DATEADD(hour, 12, @shift_end);
    END
    INSERT INTO @Output(equipment, equipment_state, equipment_state_in, equipment_state_out, shift_begin, shift_end)
            VALUES (@equipment, @equipment_state, @equipment_state_in, @equipment_state_out, @shift_begin, @shift_end)

    SET @RowNum += 1; 
END

SELECT * FROM @Output
```